# IE-10 prints table contents in small font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

An iframe is used to print the table contents displayed in application. The table contents are added to an aspx page at runtime and that page is source of iframe. Below method is used to print that table:

```
 window.frames["PrintFrame"].focus();
 window.frames["PrintFrame"].print();
```

It works fine on IE-7 to IE-9, But in IE-10 it prints table's contents with small font.
I have realized that the [jQuery Splitter Plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/3psplitter.html) which is used in application causes that problem. Because, when I remove the link of [js file](http://methvin.com/splitter/splitter-152.js) of that plugin it works fine on IE-10 too.

While debuging application, I come to know that plugin applies some settings on iframes in the window. But, why this is only affecting IE-10.

Help will be appreciated.

Note: I have displayed the contents instead of printing from ifram, here style is as expected and when I print from that window, it prints as expected. But, problem is only when printing with iframe.

Comment: Check the browser and document modes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just shifted compatibility tag from EmulateIE8 to EmulateIE7. Now, it working as required on IE-10.